# How to use $geoNear after $lookup

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Hi i have the following problem:
I would like to use $geoNear (to count distance between two points) but after $loopback (and on collection that i joined).
This is the model for companyBases collection (i would like to join it):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7cfe13f42e7345d967b378"),
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            20.633856,
            49.761268
        ]
    },
    "vehicles" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d7cfe13f42e7345d967b340"),
            ...other fields that doesn't matter
        }
    ]
}
```

This is vehicle collection:

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d7cfe13f42e7345d967b340"),
            ...other fields that doesn't matter
}
```

I would like to join companyBase collection in aggregation on vehicles collection:

```
db.vehicles.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "companybases",
      let: {
        vehicleId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $in: ["$$vehicleId", "$vehicles._id"] }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "companyBases"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$companyBases"
  },
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [50.02485, 20.0008]
      },
      distanceField: "distance",
      spherical: true
    }
  }
]);
```

But it returns me:

```
{
    "message" : "$geoNear is only valid as the first stage in a pipeline.",
    "operationTime" : "Timestamp(1568472833, 1)",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 40602,
    "codeName" : "Location40602",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : "Timestamp(1568472833, 1)",
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=",
            "keyId" : "0"
        }
    },
    "name" : "MongoError"
}
```

When i am doing the same pipeline on companybases collection it returns me documents with counted distance:

```
db.companybases.aggregate([
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [50.02485, 20.0008]
      },
      distanceField: "distance",
      spherical: true
    }
  }
]);
```

And result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7cfe13f42e7345d967b378"),
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            20.633856,
            49.761268
        ]
    },
    "vehicles" : [
        {
            ...some fields
        },

    ],
    ...some fields
    "distance" : 4209673.447019393
}
```

I realize that the error may be because of missing index on vehicles collection. So is there any way to calculate distance with $geoNear with $lookup ? Or maybe it's impossible and i have to do on my own ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple solutions (you can put $geoNear in $lookup pipeline):

```
db.vehicles.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "companybases",
      let: {
        vehicleId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $geoNear: {
            near: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: [50.02485, 20.0008]
            },
            distanceField: "distance",
            spherical: true
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $in: ["$$vehicleId", "$vehicles._id"] }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "companyBases"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$companyBases"
  }
]);
```

But that strongly impressed the performance (it takes at least 5 seconds), becuase $geoNear is used before match.

Answer (score -2):

your  error shows `"message" : "$geoNear is only valid as the first stage in a pipeline.",`

it is  clear  that  you can't  put '$geoNear' after  `$lookup`

so  **You can only use $geoNear as the first stage of a pipeline.**

just  to  exchange you agg  order 
use `$geoNear` at first  then with `$lookup`

Comment: Exchanging order is not an option when the location data is in the looked up data